# How to output Tick Box Grid Responses from Google Forms to Google Sheets as Separate Columns (plus calculates Timezone)?

Tags: forms, api, google-sheets, formula, google-forms

I need something where our Team Members can select their regular Hours of Availability during the week, in 1 hour intervals, and the results of all Team Members can be seen in a Spreadsheet (and if they fill it out 2 or more times, it will just update their last response). From there, selecting Meeting Times where specific Members can meet should be *a lot* simpler!

It occurred to me recently that **Google Forms** and **Google Sheets** could be one of the best solutions here! But I really don't have much experience with [Google Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/) (which it looks like I'm going to need to do what I want it to do), and so I have some questions:

1. I have a [7 x 24 (7 Days of the Week by 24 1-Hour Intervals) **Tick Box Grid** (see linked image here)](https://ibb.co/tc0BXYt). How can I set it up so it can [output each Row+Column in its own separate Column in the output Google Sheet (see linked image here for my preferred output for a single Day)](https://ibb.co/8XxQ86S)?

   - In case you're wondering what is going on with the 3rd Row: I have SUM Functions `=iferror(counta(L4:L62))` (where L is the Letter of the Column) to Total the "Checked Responses" in each Column for an easy glance of the number of **X**s (*Yeses*) for each Hour Block Column.
2. How can I customize each Row+Column Checked Response so it outputs as a simple letter **X**?
3. I also have a **Dropdown** Timezone Question, where it asks the User select their Timezone from 1 of the 25 available Timezones in the world. I would like it so their responses to the Hours of Availability **Tick Box Grid** is modified to match their responses in GMT. So for example, if I select my Timezone as `GMT -4`, and in the **Tick Box Grid** I select `12AM to 1AM` on `Sunday`, the Google Sheet will include an **X** under `7PM to 8PM` on `Saturday`?

Am I asking for too much from Google Forms + Google Sheets API here? And if I am, maybe there is a better Cloud Program I could use for handling this?

Comment: Here's a blank sheet.  Let's get started by pasting some data there.  It will make it a little easier to explain/demonstrate the functions you'll need to use.  It will also never be deleted.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g5S5Nyfwr8eHWyn-UXVfdbVj8tdZeY-lU20C2VxuCZ8/edit

Comment: Thank you @MattKing for your offer to help!

Comment: Edited the "Build Sample here" with my desired Output Sheet.

Since my original post, one of my Team's Developers has been helping with building the Google Sheet. Some of our current progress:
1. Instead of GMT, conversions should be to UTC so we don't need to calculate DST
2. The "Form Responses" shouldn't be modified at all Manually/by Script. Instead, a separate Tab is created where the Results from "Form Responses" go into (looking like the "Build sample here" Tab looks like in your Doc)
3. Use REGEX instead of Google Scripts

We've run into problems when a result goes between days.

Comment: Hi ! Please read Stack Overflow guidelines on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Each question should only include a single question not multiple (yours have three, please create a separate question for each one of them). Please edit your question so that you are only asking one of these questions in your post.

Comment: My apologies @MateoRandwolf. I intended to ask my 3 Questions as separate questions, but I thought the 3 were so interrelated that I might as well ask all 3 in 1 Question. The first question was the main one. No point to separating these questions now, as MattKing answered all 3 (and then some) when he worked closely with me yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So @MattKing (Matthew King) worked closely with me yesterday to get my Tick Box Grid to output to Google Sheets as I intended, as well as handling Timezone Conersion! You can see the Test Results in here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g5S5Nyfwr8eHWyn-UXVfdbVj8tdZeY-lU20C2VxuCZ8/edit

I should first mention that the Form Output Sheet (called **Form responses**) should NOT be modified. Also NO Google API Scripting has been required to get Google Sheets to format the Form Results as I want to. Instead, new Sheets with Formulas (rather complex ones might I add) was the way to go!

- To output 1 Hour increments of 24 hours for 7 days: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SEQUENCE(1,24*7,0)/24+1)`
- Each **Name** in "Form Responses" (in Column A) can be output, in alphabetical order, as follows: `=QUERY({'Form responses'!B2:C},"select Col1 where Col2 is not null order by Col1")`
- **Hours of Availability** in "Form Responses" (in Columns E through AB) can be output (where each Column is 1 of 24 hours in 1 of 7 days) as follows: `=IF($A4="",,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A4&TEXT(B$2,"ddd hh"),UTCData!$A:$A,0)),"X",))`
- If I want to have separate Meetings in separate Sheets, and I have the Meeting Name (selected as Checkboxes in the Form) in A1, then I can set it up so only the Names of the People who checked that Meeting will be shared as follows: `=QUERY({'Form responses'!B2:C},"select Col1 where Col2 Contains'"&A1&"' order by Col1")`

He also created for me 2 Sheets that handle more Formula Conversions:

- **Flattened Form** Sheet

  - **Flattened Formula:** `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN('Form responses'!B2:B&"|"&'Form responses'!C2:C&"|"&'Form responses'!D2:D&"|"&MID('Form responses'!E1:AB1,64,20)&"|"&'Form responses'!E2:AB),"|",0,0),"where Col5<>''"))`
  - **Extract Times:** `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D="",,SPLIT(MID(D2:D,2,LEN(D2:D)-2)," to ",0)))`
  - **UTC Conversion:** `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(MOD(MATCH(SPLIT(E2:E,", ",0),TITLE!C10:I10,0),7)+F2:F+C2:C/24))`
- **UTCData** Sheet

  - **Name&UTCDayTimeCombos:** `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF('Flattened Form'!H2:N="",,'Flattened Form'!A2:A&TEXT('Flattened Form'!H2:N,"ddd hh"))),"where Col1<>''"))`
  - In Column **C2** - **C8**, it lists `Sunday` through `Saturday`

If you need someone to help you with your Google Sheets and Forms, I can't recommend Matt's help more!